# How to get the field data of a CLIPS fact using the Java API?

Tags: java, clips

Suppose I have some *plain* CLIPS facts (no slots):

```
(deffacts happyFacts
(happy Peter)
(happy Alex)
(happy Mary))
```

Using the Java API (CLIPSJNI), I can retrieve these facts as follows:

```
MultifieldValue mv = (MultifieldValue) clips.eval("(find-all-facts ((?f happy)) TRUE)");
```

Then I can then retrieve the first individual fact as follows:

```
FactAddressValue fact = (FactAddressValue) mv.multifieldValue().get(0);
```

If that fact had named slots, I could've obtained the field data as follows:

```
fact.getFactSlot("someSlot")
```

but it has no slots; then, how do I retrieve its field value (in this case, `Peter`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For CLIPSJNI 0.5, modify Java_net_sf_clipsrules_jni_Environment_getFactSlot in net_sf_cilpsrules_jni_Environment.c to allow a null value to be passed as the slot name:

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_net_sf_clipsrules_jni_Environment_getFactSlot(
  JNIEnv *env,
  jclass javaClass, 
  jobject javaEnv,
  jlong clipsEnv,
  jlong clipsFact,
  jstring slotName)
  {
   jobject rv;
   DATA_OBJECT theDO;
   void *theCLIPSEnv = JLongToPointer(clipsEnv);
   const char *cSlotName = NULL;

   if (slotName != NULL)
     { cSlotName = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env,slotName,NULL); }

   void *oldContext = SetEnvironmentContext(theCLIPSEnv,(void *) env);

   EnvGetFactSlot(JLongToPointer(clipsEnv),JLongToPointer(clipsFact),(char *) cSlotName,&theDO);

   if (slotName != NULL)
     { (*env)->ReleaseStringUTFChars(env,slotName,cSlotName); }

   rv = ConvertDataObject(env,javaEnv,theCLIPSEnv,&theDO);

   SetEnvironmentContext(JLongToPointer(clipsEnv),oldContext);

   return rv;
  }
```

You can then pass a null value to return the implied slot:

```
   public static void main(String args[])
     {  
      Environment clips;

      clips = new Environment();
            clips.build("(deffacts happyFacts " +
                  "  (happy Peter)" +
                  "  (happy Alex)" +
                  "  (happy Mary))");

      clips.reset();            

      clips.eval("(facts)");
      MultifieldValue mv = (MultifieldValue) clips.eval("(find-all-facts ((?f happy)) TRUE)");
      FactAddressValue fact = (FactAddressValue) mv.multifieldValue().get(0);

      try
        {
         System.out.println("Slot value is " + fact.getFactSlot(null));
        }
      catch (Exception e)
        {
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
     }
```

Comment: Sadly, `fact.getFactSlot("implied")` returns null for me.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect that the C API expects null for the implied slot whereas the CLIPS function expects the symbol implied/